# ReactJs : How to prevent componentWillUpdate from re-rendering multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am creating a simple Todo App, I am using componentDidMount to display the data from the database. But the problem is, Once I add a new data the data gets stored but it doesn't display on to the page unless I refresh it.

Then I came across componentDidUpdate. It works perfectly, But it re-renders multiple times, What I mean is it keeps requesting the server to check for new data. 
I am using Express for backend

So could anyone tell me how to prevent this ? or if there is any better solution?

Here is the current code:

```
  class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {
    userArray: [],
    username: "",
    email: ""
  };

  //Storing the Data

  addBtn = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      username: this.state.username,
      email: this.state.email
    };

    fetch("/user", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data === "success") {
          console.log("Yay");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(this.state.userArray);
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.displayData();
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    this.displayData();
  }
```

//Displaying the Data

```
  displayData() {
    fetch("/user")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          userArray: data
        });
      });
  }

  //Handling the input values

  logChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

Comment: You need to call `this.setState()` in `addBtn` when you have the data instead of repeatedly calling `this.displayData()`. Updating the state with `setState` will trigger a re-render. Currently you are scheduling a new update during an update which will lead to an infinite loop of updates. Also note that [`componentWillUpdate` is deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate) and should not be used anymore.

Comment: I tried that, But it still doesn't show the data on the screen

Comment: Then you did not do it correctly. Please add your `render()` method and how and where you called `setState`.

Comment: You can call `this.displayData()` in success callback of `fetch` call in `addBtn` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's try and understand why there was a lot of calls to the server.

When `componentDidMount` is created, you called `displayData`, which then setState. As soon as setstate is called, it calls `componentDidUpdate` which calls `displayData` again, which then calls setState. And the loop goes on (probably till you run out of memory).

You could try this class:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        userArray: [],
        username: '',
        email: ''
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.displayData();
    }

    addBtn = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {
            username: this.state.username,
            email: this.state.email
        };

        fetch('/user', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status >= 400) {
                    throw new Error('Bad response from server');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data === 'success') {
                    this.displayData();
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    displayData() {
        fetch('/user')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    userArray: data
                });
            });
    }
}
```

Basically, what I did was I removed the call to displayData in componentDidUpdate and then called the displayData when the ApI call was successful

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is the right place to load the first time, and then, after creating new Todo, you need to refresh the list right after **POST** request complete

```
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data === "success") {
    console.log("Yay");
    this.displayData();
  }
})
```

To impove performace, you should return new Todo record after `POST`, so you only push it to the list `userArray` in state, no need to fetch whole list again

Comment: Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to first understand how componentDidMount and componentWillUpdate works in React.
They are [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) of react.

componentDidMount gets called after the component is mounted. It gets called only once and never gets called again if not unmounted and mounted again.

componentWillUpdate gets called every time state changes and re-rendering is going to happen.

As commented by  @trixn:
You need to call this.setState() in addBtn when you have the data instead of repeatedly calling this.displayData()

Comment: Okay, so should I unmount and then mount again?

Answer (score 0):

Everyone gave the right answer , But there is a tiny mistake.

You should call the `displayData()` outside of the `if condition`

```
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data === "success") {
    console.log("Yay");
  }
   this.displayData();
})
```